# Uniform Convergence for Vectors

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, it.information-theory, limits-and-convergence, measure-concentration

$\textbf{Problem statement:}$

Let $\mathcal H:\mathcal X \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ be a class of Boolean functions for $\mathcal X \subset \mathbb R^n$, and let the [VC Dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VC_dimension) of $\mathcal H$ be $VC_{dim}(\mathcal H)=d < \infty$.
For every binary vector $(a,b)$, we define the normalization function $g$ as follows:

$$g(a,b)= 
\begin{cases}
 \frac {(a,b)}{|a+b|} & a+b>0 \\
  (0,0) &a+b = 0
\end{cases}.
$$

Let $\mathcal F \triangleq g \circ (\mathcal H \times \mathcal H)$,  such that $f(x)=g(h_1(x),h_2(x))$, for every $x\in \mathcal X$ and $h_1,h_2\in \mathcal H$.

Let $\mathcal D$ be a measure over $\mathcal X$. For all $f\in \mathcal F$ define:
$$ 
L_\mathcal D(f)=\int_{\mathcal X}f(x)d\mathcal D.
$$
In addition, for a sample $\mathcal S$ drawn i.i.d. from $\mathcal D$ of size $m$, we define

$$
\hat L_\mathcal S(f)=\frac 1 m \sum_{i=1}^m f(x_i).
$$

---

Congrats if you got so far :). I wish to bound 
$$
\Pr_{\mathcal S \sim \mathcal D^m}\left( \sup_{f\in \mathcal F} \mid\mid{L_\mathcal D(f) -  \hat L_\mathcal S(f)\mid\mid}_1 \geq \epsilon\right)
$$

as a function of $m,\epsilon$ and $d$. I am not sure how to use the $VC$ dimension in order to do so, nor how to use [standard uniform convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence_in_probability) arguments.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm confused -- is the argument to $g$ a single vector or a pair of bits?

Comment: Either would work, but I agree the latter makes more sense. I change it accordingly, thanks

Comment: How do you define $g(0,0)$?

Comment: @AryehKontorovich to be zero vector, thanks again.

Comment: Why do you have the $\ell_1$ norm for the difference of the two losses? They're real numbers, so isn't it just an absolute value?

Comment: @AryehKontorovich The loss functions are not real-valued. $L_{\mathcal D}(f)$ is a vector, and so is $\hat L_{\mathcal S}(f)$

Comment: Got it thanks. Unless I’m missing something this should be simple, will hopefully write an answer soon (unless someone beats me to it).

Comment: @AryehKontorovich A hint will also be great :)

Comment: The answer below contains a hint.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\tilde g(a,b)=(a,b)$ be the ``unnormalized'' version of $g$,
define $\tilde f(x):=\tilde g(h_1(x),h_2(x))$,
and note that $$
\frac12 L_D(\tilde f)
\le
L_D(f)
\le
L_D(\tilde f)
$$
where the inequality holds coordinate-wise;
this is because $\frac12\tilde g\le g\le\tilde g$.
Analogously,
$
\frac12 \hat L_S(\tilde f)
\le
\hat L_S(f)
\le
\hat L_S(\tilde f)
$.

Now let $m=\Theta(\frac{d}{\epsilon^2}\log\frac1\delta)$ be
large enough to guarantee that
$$ P\left\{ \sup_{h\in H} |L_D(h)-\hat L_S(h)|>\epsilon\right\}<\delta,$$
where $L_D(h),\hat L_S(h)$ are defined in the obvious way.

Thus, with probability $1-\delta$, each component of $L_D(\tilde f)$
is $\epsilon$-close to its empirical counterpart and their $\ell_1$-distance
is at most $2\epsilon$.

It follows that for $m$ as chosen above,
$$
P\left\{ \sup_{f\in F} ||L_D(f)-\hat L_S(f)||>2\epsilon\right\}<\delta.
$$

EDIT:
This argument doesn't work. Note that the function $g$ is discontinuous on $[0,1]^2$: it maps $(x,x)$ to $(1/2,1/2)$, even for very small $x$. I'm not even sure I think convergence still holds, will have to think some more...

EDIT 2:

This may be an overkill, but at least I think it works.
Let us bound the $\gamma$-fat shattering dimension of
the function class $\mathcal{F}$, componentwise.
Let $\mathcal{F}_1$ denote the set of all $u:\mathcal{X}\to[0,1]$
such that $f(x)\equiv (u(x),v(x))$ for some $f\in\mathcal{F}$.
Note that $u$ can only take on the values $\{0,1/2,1\}$.
It's easy to see that if $\mathcal{H}$ cannot shatter more than $d$ points,
then $\mathcal{F}_1$ cannot $\gamma$-shatter more than $2d$ points, for any $\gamma>0$.
(Certainly $\mathcal{F}_1$ cannot $(\gamma>1/2)$-shatter more than $d$ points, and the other component
can contribute at most another $d$ points at scale $\gamma\le1/2$).

Once you have that the $\gamma$-shattering dimension of both components $\mathcal{F}_1$
(and the analogously defined an analyzed $\mathcal{F}_2$) is finite, standard uniform convergence
results apply. In particular, $\hat L_S(f)$ converges to $L_D(f)$ componentwise,
uniformly over $f\in\mathcal{F}$, at a distribution-free rate.

For specific rates, see e.g.,
Alon et al., Scale-sensitive Dimensions, Uniform Convergence, and Learnability:
http://www.tau.ac.il/~nogaa/PDFS/learn3.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the response. I can see why the last inequality holds if we replace $f$ with $\tilde f$ (as the text just above the inequality explains), but I fail to see why the inequality holds as you wrote it . Where did you use $\frac12\tilde g\le g\le\tilde g$?

Comment: It was used to establish the first large-display inequality.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why the last inequality holds for $f$? I can only see why it holds for $\tilde f$...

Comment: Because f is sandwiched between 1/2 tilde f and tilde f.

Comment: ... as in that first display.

Comment: I probably miss something. How can one, using the first display and the empirical distribution analog, bound $||L_D(f)-\hat L_S(f)||$ using the $\tilde f$ equivalents ? I would appreciate if you could provide the claims for bounding $||L_D(f)-\hat L_S(f)||$ using $L_D(\tilde f),\hat L_S(\tilde f)$. Sorry for being blind here....

Comment: You're right -- see my edit.

Comment: Not sure it helps, but $g$ is defined over the set of binary vectors only.

Comment: @omerbp I think I have a fix.